# adapter.CustomListAdapter.getCount Exception

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

```
private List<Product> movieList = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

In my "Favorite" Fragment, If I get my favorite list:

```
movieList = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity); // movieList is some data that I get with JSON
```

Before initializing my custom adapter:

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(activity, movieList);
```

I'll get this exception:

> > java.lang.NullPointerException
> >     at com.company.myapp.adater.CustomListAdapter.getCount(CustomListAdapter.java:63)
> >     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:463)

And if I get favorite list after initializing adapter my favorite list will not show anything.

"This exception will come up only if my favorite list is empty"

**Fragment**

```
public class ZZZFavorites extends Fragment{

View view ;
Activity activity;
SharedPreference sharedPreference;

private static final String url = "http://symphonyrecords.ir/apps/ringtone/movies2.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Product> movieList = new ArrayList<Product>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = getActivity();
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_hive_main_activity, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);


    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    movieList = sharedPreference.getFavorites(activity);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(activity, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
            hidePDialog();

            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    Product movie = new Product();
                    movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                    movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                    movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating")).doubleValue());
                    movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id"));

                    // Genre is  array
                    JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                    ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                        genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                    }
                    movie.setGenre(genre);

                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("TAG", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

     return view;
   }

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {




private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Product> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

SharedPreference sharedPreference;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Product> movieItems) {
    super(activity, R.layout.android_hive_list_row, movieItems);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
    sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
}


static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView title ;
    private TextView rating ;
    private TextView genre ;
    private TextView year ;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Product getItem(int position) {
    return movieItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_hive_list_row, null);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        holder.genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        holder.year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    Product m = movieItems.get(position);


    holder.title.setText(m.getTitle());

    holder.rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    holder.genre.setText(genreStr);

    holder.year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: put all your code here please

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra by all you mean my favorite fragment or ALL of it?

Comment: the fragment and the adapter as well.

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra  I've edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getCount() method to this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(movieItens == null{
     return 0;
     } else {
    return movieItens.isEmpty()? 0 : movieItems.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I do it to avoid NullPointerException in my Adapters. Doing so, your recyclerView will know that the list have no data to show. 
Can you accept the answer please?